# Make a call from the card view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to take numbers from the recycler view list and then make a call by click on a button i cant do the code for this help me to figure out from this.

```
@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_asi_details);

    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dimageviewasi);
    textView_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dtextviewasi);
    textView_email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dtextviewasi1);
    textView_mobile=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dtextviewasi2);
    imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("img_id",00));
    textView_name.setText("Name: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
    textView_email.setText("e-Mail: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("email"));
    textView_mobile.setText("Mobile: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"));

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.asibutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.aks_phone);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: *take numbers from the recycler view list* I didnt understand

Comment: means i want to put mobile numbers to every listed member of the recycler vieww

Comment: Please provide your recyclerview code here . You need to create a adapter for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

use code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
```